# ASP.NET MVC 6 + EF6 with Migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd like to use ASP.NET MVC 6 with Entity Framework 6 with Migrations enabled.  My Entity Framework 6 DbContext is in a separate assembly from the MVC 6 project.  I can get Entity Framework 6 to work with MVC 6, but as soon as I enable Migrations, I get a `FileNotFoundException` with the message `Could not find file '{AssemblyName}.resources'.`

[image]

Is there a way to get MVC 6 to work with EF 6 with Migrations?

Here's a test project I put on GitHub that demonstrates the problem: https://github.com/johnnyoshika/mvc6-ef6-migrations

Comment: Can you continue? Some Microsoft components use a "try and if not found create" mechanismn to create internal structures (e.g. the Xsl part of System.Xml does similar things)...

Comment: What do you exactly do when you get that error?

Comment: Thanks for the comments @StephenReindl and @JotaBe!  I will check later today whether I can continue past this exception.

Comment: It is exactly the same for me - "FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code", so server just responds with 500 Internal Server Error. The code just creates context and tries to add a record when it happens.

Comment: I see the same result as @DmitryNogin.  FileNotFoundException leads to a 500 error.  Here's a test project I put on GitHub that demonstrates the problem: https://github.com/johnnyoshika/mvc6-ef6-migrations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem in beta7.  It would seem ASP.NET 5 does not play nicely with resources (.resx) embedded in csproj projects.  If you locally reference aspnet/Mvc and Entityframework (6), you'll see it's trying to show some helpful debug information, but does so using localisation.  In your example it's trying to access the `LoggingTargetDatabase` field from [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Properties/Resources.resx) but incorrectly expecting it to be embedded in `Entity2` rather than `EntityFramework`, due to what I suspect is ASP.NET 5's lacking support for .resx.

This was one of several issues I found attempting to get EF6 migrations in ASP.NET 5, and in the end I wrote a small DNX Command library [[Github](https://github.com/staff0rd/entityframework-migrations) | [myget](https://www.myget.org/F/atquin)] that would call EF6 migrations programatically, similar to how [EF7](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/tree/dev/src/EntityFramework.Commands) does it.

Comment: Thank you @StaffordWilliams.  I'm having a hard time getting your library to work.  Which dependency are you mapping to the `ef` command?  Is it `EntityFramework.Commands` or `Atquin.EntityFramework.Migrations`?  Also, my DbContext is in a separate assembly.  Is the `config.json` file expected to be there or in the MVC 6 project?

Comment: @JohnnyOshika Atquin.EntityFramework.Migrations should be mapped inside your data project.config to ef.  Config.json should be in data project as well, or, you can specify provider & connection string with -p and -c.

Comment: works like a charm.  A couple of things that tripped me up.  1) I didn't realize that I had to manually create a class that inherits from `DbMigrationsConfiguration`.  2) I couldn't get the connection string discovery in config.json to work, so I used the command line args.  It's working really well now.  Thank you!